# ROS-driven Gazebo does not work since GPU handles it

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, virtualbox, ros

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 along with ROS Noetic distribution through a **virtual machine** (Oracle Virtualbox). I want to run Gazebo simulations: they **used to work** but I did not have enough FPS, so **I allocated a part of my NVIDIA GPU** to my virtual machine (thgh the NVIDIA pannel control, I set virtualboxvm.exe to be handled by the dedicated GPU) and enabled 3D acceleration in the VM settings. **Gazebo on itself works better** in terms of FPS (60 FPS which is very satisfactory), but when I try to use ROS (*roslaunch turtlebot3_gazebo turtlebot3_house.launch*) I get the following error :

```
[gazebo-2] process has died [pid 2638, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/noetic/lib/gazebo_ros/gzserver -e ode /home/tristan/catkin_ws/src/turtlebot3_simulations/turtlebot3_gazebo/worlds/turtlebot3_house.world __name:=gazebo __log:=/home/tristan/.ros/log/66282280-8cd2-11eb-9803-f1f00516ff4d/gazebo-2.log].
log file: /home/tristan/.ros/log/66282280-8cd2-11eb-9803-f1f00516ff4d/gazebo-2*.log
```

I am a beginner in both Linux and ROS, so I may have missed something obvious (drivers? BIOS settings?). However, my problem definitely comes from the fact that I now use my GPU.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Disable 3D acceleration in VM. Gazebo will work.